# How to show the words "empty cart" when an item is removed from the shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The code to remove the item is already built and is working perfectly(I remove the item by the database, not with the remove button-icon yet), besides that what I'm trying to do is simply display a message in  saying "The cart is empty" when the item is removed from the cart... I could do that with jquery but if I do it with jquery it might break the php code. I can't figure out a way to do that. I want to display "The cart is empty" when there's no item in the [cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVSTE.png)(Take a look at the picture), in the words, how to display a div when a variable is true? I tried to do it with something like this. This code is inside a while loop:

```
<?php $grand_total += $row['total_price']; ?>
  <h1 class="<?= ($grand_total > 1) ? "class='hideThis'" : "class='showThis'" ?>">The cart is empty</h1>
```

and this is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Carrinho</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3da1a747b2.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semanticModificado.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="payment.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cart.css">
    <style>
        .hideThis {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .showThis {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="navmobile" style="display: none">
        <img src="upload\felinefilogo.svg" style="margin-top: 1rem" height="100px" width="250px" alt="">
        <img src="upload\felinefi.svg" height="20px" width="62.5px" alt="">
        <nav class="navbar" style="padding: 0; margin-right: 16px">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart2.php" display="none" class="nav-item nav-link active">
                        <h5 class="px-5 cart" style="display: flex;">
                            &nbsp;Carrinho&nbsp;
                            <span id="cart-item" class="cart-item text-warning bg-light"></span> &nbsp;
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-flip-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar" id="navdesktop">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="imagem"><img src="upload\felinefihorizontalmedium.svg" height="100px" width="250px" alt="">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index2.php">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart2.php" display="none" class="nav-item nav-link active">
                        <h5 class="px-5 cart" style="display: flex;">
                            &nbsp;Carrinho&nbsp;
                            <span id="cart-item" class="cart-item text-warning bg-light"> </span> &nbsp;
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-flip-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="section-aPayment">
        <div class="containerPayment">
            <div class="row" style="flex-wrap:nowrap" !important>
                <div class="col-75">
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="meuCarrinho">Meu carrinho</h2>
                    <br>
                    <form action="">
                        <?php
                        require 'config.php';
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart");
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $result = $stmt->get_result();
                        $grand_total = 0;
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) :
                            ?>
                            <div class="cartContainer">
                                <div class="sub-container">
                                    <div class="imagem2"><img src="<?= $row['product_image'] ?>" alt=""></div>
                                    <div class="conteudodaDiv">
                                        <div class="title-e-icon">
                                            <h3><?= $row['product_name'] ?></h3> <!-- <button class="icon" name="remove"> --><a href="action.php?remove=<?= $row['id'] ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Ref: <span># D12-9970-014-39</span></p>
                                        <p>Vendido por <a href="index2.php">Felinefi</a> e entregue em até 8 dias úteis. </p>
                                        <p>Frete GRÁTIS</p>
                                        <p>Tamanho: <span>39 </span></p>
                                        <p>Cor: <span>Preto</span> </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="eita">
                                    <h1>Quantidade:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <button type="button" class="ui circular button" id="menos"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="-5 -15 39 39">
                                                <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-12v-2h12v2z" />
                                            </svg></button>
                                        <div class="ui mini icon input focus">
                                            <input class="qty" value="<?= $row['qty'] ?>" type="text" style="padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 12px; width: 34px;" maxlength="1" disabled="">
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="button" class="ui circular button" id="mais"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="-5 -15 39 39">
                                                <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z" />
                                            </svg></button>
                                    </h1>
                                    <div class="price">
                                        <span>R$ 79.90</span><span>R$ <?= number_format($row['product_price'], 2) ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php $grand_total += $row['total_price']; ?>
                    <h1 class="<?= ($grand_total > 1) ? "class='hideThis'" : "class='showThis'" ?>">The cart is empty</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-25">
                    <br>
                    <h2>Resumo da compra</h2>
                    <br>
                    <div class="containerResumo">
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda1">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Itens</h3>
                            <h3 class="direita2">(<?= $row['qty'] ?>)</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subCoDireita2">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Desconto</h3>
                            <h3 class="direita2" id="hidethisDiv"> 50% </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda3">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Valor total</h3>

                            <h3 class="direita2">R$ <?= number_format($grand_total, 2); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda4">
                            <a href="payment.php"><button class="positive fluid ui button">Continuar</button></a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $("input[name='expyear']").mask("00 / 00");
        $("input[name='zip']").mask("00000 - 000");
    </script>

    <script>
        //a condição surte efeito quando a página da reload ou aperta f5.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($(this).width() < 500) {

                $('#navdesktop').hide();
                $('#navmobile').show();

            } else if ($(this).width() > 500) {

                $('#navmobile').hide();
                $('#navdesktop').show();

            }
        });
        //a condição surte efeito apenas quando mexe na "responsividade" da página.
        $(window).resize(function() {

            if ($(this).width() < 500) {

                $('#navdesktop').hide();
                $('#navmobile').show();

            } else if ($(this).width() > 500) {

                $('#navmobile').hide();
                $('#navdesktop').show();

            }

        });
    </script>

    <script>
        //aumentar e diminuir a quantidade dos itens (respectivamente).
        $(function() {
            $('#mais').on('click', function() {
                var $qty = $(this).closest('h1').find('.qty');
                var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
                if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                    $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
                }
            });
            $('#menos').on('click', function() {
                var $qty = $(this).closest('h1').find('.qty');
                var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
                if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                    $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        //ajax.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            load_cart_item_number();

            function load_cart_item_number() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'action.php',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {
                        cartItem: "cart-item"
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.cart-item').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //mostra o conteúdo do carrinho quando a página carrega depois de clicar em "Adicionar ao Carrinho".
        window.onload = function() {
            if (!window.location.hash) {
                window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but what you have will put a `class=` within (inside) the other class attribute.

Try this instead:

```
<h1 class="<?= ($grand_total > 1) ? 'hideThis' : 'showThis' ?>">The cart is empty</h1>
```

Comment: T That's IT! I just had to put the <h1> tag somewhere else. Thank you very much!!!